# Camera store near Split, Croatia?

Tags: shopping, photography, croatia, split

I'm travelling in Croatia with my Canon 5D Mark II, and I forgot my charger at home. Is there a store in or around Split that would sell such a thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A place where you most definitely have Canon products is [Anigota](http://www.anigota.com) which is a Canon dealer for Croatia. You can find their store in [Gundulićeva 26](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=gunduli%C4%87eva+26+split&hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=43.514207,16.438401&spn=0.004007,0.010568&sll=45.840196,15.964332&sspn=0.246354,0.676346&t=h&hnear=Ulica+Ivana+Gunduli%C4%87a+26,+21000,+Split,+Op%C4%87ina+Split+%C5%BEupanija,+Croatia&z=17&layer=c&cbll=43.514206,16.438553&panoid=vPrjIC8cr0iJfBbcnuOPpg&cbp=12,190.31,,0,2.35) in Split.

The store is called "Kodak centar d.o.o." and it's near "Panasonic centar".

According to their website, they're open Mondays - Fridays 08:00 - 20:00 and Saturdays 08:00 - 13:00.

Comment: Bah, good find, I had the name Anigota but couldn't get the website to work last night.

Comment: Found it! Unfortunately they didn't have what I needed, but thanks!

Comment: Too bad... Hope they told you where to get it.

Answer (score 5):

The Joker Centre is a good possibility - it was the first major mall to open in Split, back in 2007, and has over 50 outlets of major global brands.

Odds are good that an electronics store exists, and that they could help you. At the very least they could direct you to somewhere else who does.

The address is:

*Put Brodarice 6*

near the [Diocletian Palace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diocletian%27s_Palace) & City Centre

Comment: Yes, the electronics store exists on the second floor of Joker; and it has a good selection.