# Where to print science posters in Paris?

Tags: paris, conferences

I am going to Paris for a conference, but I failed to print a poster at home. How can I find a poster printing service with immediate printing of A0/A1/A2 posters in Paris (from pdf)?

Comment: This is by far the most travel related question i ever had. If at least some of the closers had the guts to motivate their decision to close.

Comment: Where is the travel content? It does not really fit into what is allowed here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq#questions

Comment: One could even argue that this is a shopping question. In fact, you are seeking to buy a service rather than a commodity.

Comment: It is as much travel related as some one asking where to buy metro tickets on the Eurostar and I can't give you tons of examples of similar questions.

Comment: Walk around the [Latin Quarter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Quarter,_Paris), especially near [Jussieu](http://maps.google.fr/maps?q=Jussieu,+Paris&hl=fr&ll=48.846093,2.355645&spn=0.011212,0.013282&sll=50.529025,2.893638&sspn=2.77282,3.400269&oq=Jussieu&t=h&hnear=Jussieu&z=16&iwloc=A) or [rue Saint-Jacques](http://maps.google.fr/maps?q=Rue+Saint-Jacques,+Paris&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&sll=48.846093,2.355645&sspn=0.011212,0.013282&oq=rue+Saint-Ja,+Paris&t=h&hnear=Rue+Saint-Jacques,+Paris,+%C3%8Ele-de-France&z=15). You're bound to hit a printing shop that can do this.

Comment: @MarcelC. This question is not so much about which shop to go to, but how to locate such a shop at short notice. This requires local expertise more than knowledge of printing shops. So I think it's a travel question, as much as “where are the skiing resorts located” or “how to get cheap plane tickets”.

Comment: I agree, definitely a travel question.

Comment: @Andra: Buying train tickets is related to travel. Because you buy a ticket to *travel* from one place to another. Whereas printing a poster ... Well it's maybe a train ticket you want to print?

Comment: Wrong, buying train tickets doesn't posit train travel. And since Andra is not from Paris, he IS traveling therefore he needs expertise of someone who can help him while traveling, no matter what he is asking for. His question is essentially the same as other questions on this site such as [Camera store near Split, Croatia?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9793/camera-store-near-split-croatia).

Comment: To me, that question is off-topic too. And am I supposed to know if he is from Paris or not?

Comment: "I am going to Paris for a conference, but I failed to print a poster at home.", maybe?

Comment: "where to buy this medicine in Rome... or where to get that thing from new york" are the same as this question and there are some questions in Travel.SE already with similar forms... I am voting to re-open...

Comment: this question asks whether business travel is on-topic. I think so. Leisure travel is not the only kind!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Pages Jaunes](http://www.pagesjaunes.fr/) or at [Qype](http://www.qype.fr/). With some luck you might even find a shop nearby ...

Comment: really? you voted to close AND answered it??