# Can I print a science poster in Berlin within one day?

Tags: germany, berlin, conferences

I am traveling to Berlin next week to present a poster on a conference. Instead of bringing a poster cylinder with me on the plane, I was wondering if I could print the poster in Berlin just before going to the venue.

Comment: Didn't we already go through this with Paris?

Comment: [almost identical question was closed as well](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10801/where-to-print-science-posters-in-paris)

Comment: Probably walking by a copy-shop with an USB stick is enough. https://www.google.nl/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=copy+shop+berlin&oq=copy+shop+berlin&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i10j0i30j0i10i30.134.2829.0.3050.15.13.0.0.0.0.203.1308.7j5j1.13.0...0.0...1c.1.17.psy-ab.YLlrbMlSnr4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47810305,d.d2k&fp=df832b20fa28acb&biw=1280&bih=901

Comment: @Bernhard not really not all copy shops have a a0 printer

Comment: I have chosen to Vote to Close as Too Broad. I have found seven different shops that will print the poster on varying sizes, ranging in prices. Without knowing how much the OP is willing to spend, where he is staying, or even where he is attending the conference, there are too many options to list.

Comment: I found this question helpful. I am traveling to Berlin from the States and am trying to find a service that will allow me to upload a pdf of the poster now and pick up or have delivered the poster to a hotel near Berlin. There are several US-based services like this, but international shipping is slow and expensive.

Answer (score 7):

Sure you can! For example you can use [mediafisch.de (only in German)](http://www.mediafisch.de/grossformatdruck/plakatdruckPosterdruck-berlin.html). You can upload the files from home and pick up the posters in Berlin. A2 poster costs between 7,50 and 5,99 EUR, A0 costs between 21,99 and 19,99 EUR (depends on quantity).

I think that's not your only option, there are many poster shops in Berlin and maybe you can find one near your hotel